# How to load csv file to multiple tables in postgres (mainly concerned about best practice)

Tags: sql, python-3.x, postgresql, database-design, triggers

I'm new to DB/postgres SQL.
Scenario: 
Need to load an csv file into postgres DB. This CSV data needs to loaded into multiple tables according DB schema. I'm looking for better design using python script.

My thought:
1. Load CSV file to intermediate table in postgres
2. Write a trigger on intermediate table to insert data into multiple tables on event of insert
3. Trigger includes truncate data at end

Any suggestions for better design/other ways without any ETL tools, and also any info on modules in Python 3.

Thanks.

Comment: - Use pg_cron for scheduling jobs within postgres, partition your tables if feasible which will give you better control over purge and will be much cleaner. Thirdly loading csv is pretty straight forward using this :   Copy tablename(col1, col2) from ‘/pathto/csv/file.csv’ DELIMITER ‘,’ CSV HEADER;

Comment: @RajVerma I think pg_cron is for scheduling based on time. I need to populate the data in all other tables from intermediate table (loaded from csv data using copy command) immediately. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Yup so what i’m saying is based on the frequency of change in data in the intermediate table or new data write a function/trigger whatever works and then populate the data to the new tables. There are several ways in which you can make use of pg_cron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using a trigger, use an explicit `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement. That is probably faster, since it is not invoked per row.

Apart from that, your procedure is fine.